# Error in Google Chrome pdf viewer

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-reader

From a couple of days my Google Chrome pdf viewer doesn't work. Whenever I try to open a pdf, nonsensical characters show up (see the image below).

[image: Google Chrome pdf viewer gives a nonsensical output]

Apart from the vertical watermark, all the characters are messed up. If I save the file on my pc and then I open it with another pdf-viewer everything works perfectly, hence the problem is strictly related to Chrome. What's strage is that the Ctrl-f function works well even for the messed-up pdf: if i look for "Hello", a string of nonsensical characters is enlightened, exactly where the actual word "Hello" is present in the correct pdf.

Any idea on how to solve this big problem?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Chrome opens PDF files in the Chrome browser window.
To disable this and have PDF files open in your PDF reader program (Adobe Reader or other), follow the steps below.

```
Open Google Chrome
In the Chrome address bar, type about:plugins or chrome://plugins and press Enter.  

Disable the Chrome PDF Viewer plug-in by clicking the Disable link for that plug-in.
```

To enable the ability for Chrome to open and display PDF files in the Chrome browser window, follow the following steps:

- Click chrome settings in your Chrome Browser (the up right corner of the `Address Bar`) and then scroll down, click on `Show advanced settings` and then under the 'Privacy' section click on `Content settings`.
  In the box that pops up scroll down to Plugins.
  (OR Chrome Menu Button icon --> Settings --> Click Show advanced settings --> In the "Privacy section", click the Content settings button)
- Look for the Adobe PDF Reader and Enable it  (Before this step Install Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat if it is not already installed)

For more information read [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/L5ESeF1UWrg)